# C# Link interface class with a generic

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, generics, interface

I have 3 class and I need to tie them with a generic. I tried this way, but this don't help. Because I do not have access to the fields of the Sp.

Ch

```
 using System;
 using UnityEngine;

 public abstract class Ch<C, S> : MonoBehaviour
        where C : Ch<C, S>
        where S : Sp<S, C>
 {

     public void Connect()
     {
         S.iii = 10;
     }

 }
```

Sp

```
using UnityEngine;

public abstract class Sp<S, C> : Singleton<Sp<S, C>>
    where S : Sp<S, C>
    where C : Ch<C, S>
{

    public static int iii = 0;

}
```

UPD. If I convert the code to the following form. I get an errors "The type Ch cannot be used as type parameter C in the generic type Up. There is no implict reference conversation from Ch to Ch>>"

```
using UnityEngine;

public abstract class Sp<C> : Singleton<Sp<C>>
    where C : Ch<Sp<C>>
{

    public static int i = 0;


}


using System;
using UnityEngine;

public abstract class Ch<S> : MonoBehaviour
    where S : Sp<Ch<S>>
{

    public void Connect()
    {
        S.iii = 10;
    }

}
```

Comment: You might want to post your compiler error. Also, it looks like your talking about a  [where generic constraint](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/where-generic-type-constraint) problem rather than interfaces.  If this is true, you might want to rephrase your title as question about constraints.

Comment: The compiler produces no errors. But access to the variable is not possible. But in the code editor there is a warning.The type .. in ...cs conflicts with the imported type .. in Assembly C#.

Comment: @OleksandrKryvenko: Maybe this is a Class Ambiguity case? https://stackoverflow.com/a/53294393/3346583

Comment: @Christopher I am not sure about this error. I think this is probably due to Generic restrictions. Because in the first case I have 4 warnings. 
1. The type 'Ch<C, S>' in 'c:\Users\Voossu\Desktop\Driving Range Project\Assets\[Utilitys]\Try\Ch.cs' conflicts with the imported type 'Ch<C, S>' in 'Assembly-CSharp, Version=0.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null'. Using the type defined in 'c:\Users\Voossu\Desktop\Driving Range Project\Assets\[Utilitys]\Try\Ch.cs'. [Assembly-CSharp-Editor]
S

Comment: `S` is a generic type so you can't use it in the code `S.iii = 10`.

Comment: Do yourself a favor and don't use class names like `Ch` and `Sp`. You'll thank me 6 months from now.

Comment: @zohar is not master class. Class from test scene.

Answer (score 2):

The error would have been:

> 'S' is a type parameter, which is not valid in the given context

You can't do `S.iii = 10;`, it must be `Sp<S, C>.iii = 10;`.

This compiles:

```
public abstract class Ch<C, S>
    where C : Ch<C, S>
    where S : Sp<S, C>
{
    public void Connect()
    {
        Sp<S, C>.iii = 10;
    }
}

public abstract class Sp<S, C> : Singleton<Sp<S, C>>
    where S : Sp<S, C>
    where C : Ch<C, S>
{
    public static int iii = 0;
}
```

Comment: Nice catch. I was looking at that trying to parse the multiple, self-referential generic types and got lost.

Comment: A bit not the effect that is expected. Class singleton. And to his Instance, I want access in pairs of children from this class. Couple child and respawn manager. Respawn manager is singleton. Children are multiple.

Comment: @OleksandrKryvenko - I don't understand what you mean. Can you please clarify?

Comment: I want to have two related classes in the inheritance. The first one is a respawn manager. It should contain information about all objects of the second type. At the same time, of the objects of the second type, it is necessary to manipulate the respawn manager data (for example, to count bots). I have three types of children now and in the future this number will expand. For this I would like to implement this relationship.

Comment: @OleksandrKryvenko - I think you're going to need to explain the business case that you're trying to solve because I'm struggling to understand the description of your classes.